# Camel Freemarker Example - Template Returns Null

Tags: java, null, apache-camel, freemarker

**The Problem:**

I am trying to run the Camel Freemarker Example from the Camel website [here](http://camel.apache.org/freemarker.html), so I can understand how they work together. However, I'm having a bit of trouble.

As you can see in the code below, everything is pretty much the same as what's in the documentation. I changed where the template goes, the "from" endpoint directory, and where the ftl file is. When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> headers.lastName [in template...]
```

Stack trace adds tips to find errors, then continues...

```
FTL Stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
 - Failed at: ${headers.lastName} [in template...]
```

**My Logic/What I've Tried:**

Now, I don't understand why headers.lastName is being found null. I thought that the `msg.setHeader("lastName", "Ibsen");` part was supposed to set that to Ibsen. I thought maybe I should try setting the name to `msg.setHeader("headers.lastName", "Ibsen");`, but that didn't work.

After that, I am not quite sure what else to look for. I am fairly new to both Camel and Freemarker. I think that something is not getting sent during the exchange, but I'm not sure what.
Can someone please explain why this isn't working?

Any advice is appreciated.

**Code:**

Here is the ftl:

```
Dear ${headers.lastName}, ${headers.firstName}

Thanks for the order of ${headers.item}.

Regards Camel Riders Bookstore
${body}
```

Here is the Java code:

```
public class FreemarkerExample  extends CamelTestSupport{

    private static Configuration cfg = null;

    static {
        cfg = new Configuration(new version("2.3.0"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.enableHangupSupport();
        main.addRouteBuilder(new FreemarkerExample().new MyRouteBuilder());
        main.run();
    }

    private Exchange createLetter() throws IOException, TemplateException{
        Exchange exchange = context.getEndpoint("direct:a").createExchange();

        Message msg = exchange.getIn();
        msg.setHeader("firstName", "Claus");
        msg.setHeader("lastName", "Ibsen");
        msg.setHeader("item", "Camel in Action");
        msg.setBody("PS: Next beer is on me, James");

        return exchange;
    }

    @Test
    public void testFreemarkerLetter() throws Exception {
        MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        mock.expectedMessageCount(1);
        mock.message(0).body().contains("Dear Ibsen, Claus");
        mock.message(0).body().contains("Thanks for the order of Camel in Action.");

        template.send("file:C:\\freemarkerExampleFile", createLetter());

        mock.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("file:C:\\freemarkerExampleFile\\templates")
                    .to("freemarker:file:C:\\freemarkerExampleFile\\templates\\letter.ftl")
                    .to("mock:result");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test can't work because of the "file" consumer.

A file consumer send a `GenericFile` into the route as a Body, and headers like `CamelFileName` or `CamelFileLastModified`.

When you are doing :

```
template.send("file:C:\\freemarkerExampleFile", createLetter());
```

You are creating a file in the folder "freemarkerExampleFile". This file will have a generated name, and the content of the file is the body of your message (ie, "PS: Next beer is on me, James"). The headers are lost.

Then, when you are polling with `from("file:C:\\freemarkerExampleFile")`, you  read each file on this folder, send a GenericFile, and apply on this GenericFile your template : it fails.

Il you want a route which take an Exchange, and write the template to a file, you can write :

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:test")
        .to("freemarker:classpath:/resources.fm")
        .to("file:target"); 
  }
});
context.start();

Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
headers.put("firstName", "Claus");
//...
context.createProducerTemplate().sendBodyAndHeaders(
        "direct:test", 
        "PS: Next beer is on me, James",
        headers);
```

Then you can send your exchange to the endpoint "direct:test"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I thought I needed the directory to a file to store the freemarker output? Do you know of a camel/freemarker example that I can reference (I've had trouble finding one myself)? That might help me understand what you mean.

Comment: the template will change the message in the route. you can write it in a folder if you want, by adding a `to("file:<folder>")

Comment: For anyone else who reads this thread, the answer got the null error to go away, but the example still didn't work (no file is ever sent to the "to folder" part of the the route).

Comment: I don't know why you didn't see any file, but I have updated my answer with a full example. If you don't set a header with the target filename, the name is generated from the exchange id